# How to transfer information between "input"

Tags: angular

I have two components "input". How can I transfer the entered data from the first "input" (full_name) to the second (short_name).

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
    <input formControlName="full_name" id="full_name" type="text">
    <label for="full_name">Full Name</label> 
   </div>
   <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
    <input formControlName="short_name" id="short_name" type="text">
    <label for="short_name">Short Name</label> 
   </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What you want to transfer? provide examples

Comment: You are using a reactive form, so you should listen to change events on that form (or the particular input) and handle your logic there. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using ReactiveForm just subscribe to event of full_name control

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  form = new FormGroup({
    full_name: new FormControl(),
    short_name: new FormControl()
  })

  constructor() {
    this.form.get('full_name').valueChanges.subscribe(fullName => this.form.get('short_name').setValue(fullName));
  }
}
```

You can use debounceTime to wait until a given amount of time before update

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  form = new FormGroup({
    full_name: new FormControl(),
    short_name: new FormControl()
  })

  constructor() {
    this.form.get('full_name').valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(500)).subscribe(fullName => this.form.get('short_name').setValue(fullName));
  }
}
```

Here is a working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ik3pny

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with template reference (**#** *selector*) like:

```
    <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
    <input #fullNameElement formControlName="full_name" id="full_name" type="text">
    <label for="full_name">Full Name</label> 
   </div>
   <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
    <input formControlName="short_name" id="short_name" type="text" [value]="fullNameElement.value">
    <label for="short_name">Short Name</label> 
   </div>
```